# Client Claims not being checked by Policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

We have a system that uses C# Core 2.1, IdentityServer4, and Identity to authenticate users.  Various other projects use the system for authorization.  I can create policies in my API's that check user claims; and use those policies to secure resources.  I add code similar to this in the API Sartup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
    options.AddPolicy("example",
      policy => policy.RequireClaim("claim", "data"));
  });
```

And add the following code before my API controller or specific task:

```
[Authorize(policy: "example")]
```

We have used this system for a long time.  Now we want to lock down an action so that only a specific client can do it (not their users).  But claims obtained through the grant type client_credentials are either not being added to the access token, or not being seen by the Authorization service.

Is there a way I can see what claims are in a token when it does not have openid as a scope?

Assuming the claim is there, why isn't the Authorization service able to see it?

Is there another alternative?  We want to lock down an action so that only the client apps themselves can do it.

Answer (score 0):

First you can always capture the raw tokens using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to see what claims that are actually passed to the receiver of the tokens. Then check in the User (ClaimsPrincipal) created by the authentication handler what claims it contains.

Then you need to explicitly map/add the missing claims so that the expected claims get into the claimsPrincipal User object. Some claims are removed in that process by default.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)